# Vertical-align in UL LI?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

```
<ul>
    <li class="more">aaa</li>
    <li class="moretwo">aaa</li>
    <li class="more">aaa</li>
</ul>

.more {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.moretwo {
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
  vertical-align:sub;
}
```

Why in this example vertical align doesn't working?
Is possible to make? If yes, how can i make it?

**LIVE EXAMPLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/gQM68/ with yours answers

Comment: The easiest way is: <li><sub>aaa</sub></li>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the text is aligned with respect to its line height so either you go through increasing line height and then applying vertical align

or

using padding-top

you can check this link for reference

http://jsfiddle.net/gQM68/2/

or

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

Answer (score 6):

you can use `vertical-align` with `display:table-cell`

```
.more {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.moretwo {
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:sub;
}
```

Comment: must read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/vertical-align#Values_(for_inline_elements)

Comment: why you want to use `sub` use `vertcal-align:bottom` instead, also why you have used `span`?? see
http://jsfiddle.net/gQM68/3/

Answer (score 0):

The [`vertical-align` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) applies only to inline-level and `table-cell` elements. You can work around this limitation by using a `span` element inside a `li` element and setting `vertical-align` on the `span`, e.g.

```
<li><span class="more">aaa</span></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you surround the text with a `span` and set its style like below it should work:

```
<ul>
    <li class="more"><span>aaa</span></li>
    ...
</ul>

li span {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

.more {
  ...
}

.moretwo {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Works for me (FF3). Which browser are you using?

Comment: This will never vertically align anything. I don't downvote, but if I did, this would be one.